# Rails 5 issues with Postgres SQL password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am building an application using Rails 5.0.0 set up with a Postgres database.

When I try to run any rake commands, I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied}
```

I've looked all over Stack Overflow to no avail on fixing the issue.

Here is my pg_hba.conf file:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     John                                trust
#host    replication     John        127.0.0.1/32            trust
#host    replication     John        ::1/128                 trust
```

Here is my database.yml file for development:

```
development:
 <<: *default
 database: in-the-paint_development

 # The specified database role being used to connect to postgres.
 # To create additional roles in postgres see `$ createuser --help`.
 # When left blank, postgres will use the default role. This is
 # the same name as the operating system user that initialized the database.
 # username: in-the-paint

 # The password associated with the postgres role (username).
 # password:

 # Connect on a TCP socket. Omitted by default since the client uses a
 # domain socket that doesn't need configuration. Windows does not have
 # domain sockets, so uncomment these lines.
 # host: localhost

 # The TCP port the server listens on. Defaults to 5432.
 # If your server runs on a different port number, change accordingly.
 # port: 5432

 # Schema search path. The server defaults to $user,public
 #schema_search_path: myapp,sharedapp,public

 # Minimum log levels, in increasing order:
 #   debug5, debug4, debug3, debug2, debug1,
 #   log, notice, warning, error, fatal, and panic
 # Defaults to warning.
 #min_messages: notice
```

Finally, I used the following commands to install postgres:

```
brew install postgres
mkdir -p $HOME/Library/LaunchAgents
ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/postgresql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

The big issue is that I was never prompted to provide a password when setting up Postgres, so I don't know what to provide in my database.yml. Leaving a blank ("") space does not fix the issue.

Do you know of anything I can fix in this code provided or commands I can run to help remedy this issue?

Comment: Start a psql session and check pg_users table to see what users you have. If I recall, installing PG the way you did doesn't create the default postgres user that your app is expecting.

Comment: i always look at [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-14-04) when installing postgres

Comment: Add password in database yml

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did.
1) In pgsql create a new user ,give him a password, create a database with same name as of user, give user permission to create new databases.
2) then in database.yml file

```
development:
  <<: *default
  database: appname_development #this will come by default if you specify to pg while creating app
  username: user
  password: password
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
```